# How to insert equation with multiple lines into table, without numbering?

Tags: tables, equations

I'm trying to insert an equation into a table, and there are 2 lines to the equation.  I got the idea to use parbox from other questions on this site.  SO, I tried doing this like so:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
col & $r$  & $a-b$  & $k-j$ & other & value $f(x)$ \\ \midrule
0 & \{01,0\}   & \parbox{\begin{equation} x=100 \\ y=\max \{500,673\} + 10 + 200 \end{equation}} & $8$ &  No &  N/A \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:
[image: table]

However, there are 2 problems with this:

- the newline command "\" in the equation did not work at all
- I would prefer no number of this equation, since it is inside the table.

Does anyone know of a nice way to display these equations in a table, with the modifications described above?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\parbox` has a width argument, `\parbox{3cm}` or whatever width you want, `equation` does not allow `\\ ` you could use `gather*` from `amsmath`

Comment: `\begin{table}[]` would not allow the table anywhere, it generates a warning and latex ignores the specified option.

Comment: Instead of `equation`, try using `$x=100$ \\ $y=\max ...$` inside the `\parbox`.

Comment: Does equation should be numbered? Without this request solution can be easier to find.

Comment: @Zarko, No I do not want the equation to be numbered.  You're saying that makes it easier?

Comment: However the equations should be aligned (as your solution shows).

Comment: @barbarabeeton that doesn't seem to give the desired output `$x=100$` and `$y=\max ...$` are still on the same line..

Comment: @somewhere -- `\newline` should work if `\\ ` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll >{$}l<{$} lll @{}}
\toprule
col & $r$  & a-b  & $k-j$ & other & value $f(x)$ \\ \midrule
0 & \{01,0\}   
  & \begin{aligned}[t]
      x&=100 \\
      y&=\max \{500,673\} + 10 + 200
    \end{aligned}
  & $8$ &  No &  N/A \\ 
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following soggestion where equations inserted in table are numbered, are numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} ll X[l, mode=dmath] 
                            r
                            c c  Q[c, wd=3em] 
                        @{}},
             cell{2-Z}{4} = {cmd=\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)},
             row{1}   = {m},
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=5pt}
             }
    \toprule
col & $r$       & a-b   && $k-j$    & other    & value $f(x)$  \\ 
    \midrule
0   & \{01,0\}  &   \begin{aligned}
                    x & = 100 \\
                    y & =\max \{500,673\} + 10 + 200
                    \end{aligned}
                        && 8        &  No      &  N/A          \\
1   & \{01,1\}  &   a^2 + b^2 = c^2
                        && 8        &  No      &  N/A          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{equation}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In the case that equation in table are not be numbered, above code  can be much simpler (without added column for numbering):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} ll X[l, mode=dmath] 
                            c c c 
                        @{}},
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=5pt}
             }
    \toprule
col & $r$       & a-b   & $k-j$    & other    & value $f(x)$  \\ 
    \midrule
0   & \{01,0\}  &   \begin{aligned}%[t] add in case that you like to have it top aligned
                    x & = 100 \\
                    y & =\max \{500,673\} + 10 + 200
                    \end{aligned}
                        & 8        &  No      &  N/A          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Trying to copy your solution (I like it except for the equation numbers), but I'm getting `File 'tabularray.sty' not found`.  How do I get around this?

Comment: @somewhere - Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? The reason I ask is that the `tabularray` package is of recent vintage.

Comment: @somewhere, of course is easier. Than can be dropped additional column and simplified table preamble. By this the result become the same as is shown in Mico answer.  See addendum to answer. Regarding package `tabularray`. Apparently you not have installed.  Do maybe use Overleaf?